# Dart check if part of a string in a a list of strings contains an element

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string:

```
String s = "Hel";
```

I have a list of Strings.

```
List<String> listS = ["Hello", "Goodbye"];
```

The following will print true as "Hello" contains "Hel":

```
list[0].contains(s);
```

The following will however print false:

```
list.contains(s);
```

What can I do to check if the list contains string S without giving an index? A loop is no option as I am using a ternary operator:

```
list.contains(s) ? .....
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check whether any element of the iterable satisfies test

```
test(String value) => value.contains(s);

listS.any(test);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can loop for every item an return true whenever an item contains the string as shown here :

```
String s = 'Hel';

  List<String> list = ['Egypt', 'Hello', 'Cairo'];

  bool existed = false;
  list.forEach((item) {
    if(item.contains(s)){
      existed = true;
      print(item);
    } 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart has a filtering method to work with lists

```
String s = "Hel";
List<String> listS = ["Hello", "Goodbye"];
```

The following will give you list of matching Items. You can do something with the result list

```
listS.where((element) => element.contains(s)).toList();
```

Or you can check the length if there was a match.

```
listS.where((element) => element.contains(s)).length;
```